# Linq query using a variable

Tags: c#, linq

Hi I have the following Linq in my project:

```
string claim;
claim = txtImageVerificationClaimSearch.Text;

var claimsearch = (from x in dbContext.view_ImageVerification_Shortened      
                   where(x.intClaimID = claim)
                   select new
```

I'm getting some error messages:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'
```

I know what the error means, but I don't know the syntax to fix it.
I also am getting the error message:

```
Error 2: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type    
C:\_Applications-TFS\IVS\Main\ImageVerificationSystem\ImageVerificationSystem\Default.aspx.cs   97  36  ImageVerificationSystem
```

I am also getting this:

```
Delegate 'System.Func<ImageVerificationSystem.view_ImageVerification_Shortened,int,bool>' does not take 1 arguments
```

can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Error clearly says what you doing wrong? Seems `x.intClaimID` is integer and you try to check it against a string!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that `claim` is a string and intClaimID is an int. In other words you're comparing apples and oranges.

You either need to do something like:

```
where  x.ClaimName == claim
```

Or you need to ask the user to enter a number in which case you'll have to convert it to ant int (from the string of the textbox)

```
int userClaimID = int.Parse(claim); // or TryParse
```

and then add it to your expression

```
where  x.intClaimID == userClaimID
```

Answer (score 2):

You need double `=` to do comparison. Also you are trying to compare `string` to `int`. I would suggest converting `claim` to `int` first.

```
int claimId = int.Parse(claim);

var claimsearch = (from x in dbContext.view_ImageVerification_Shortened      
                   where(x.intClaimID == claimId)
                   select x);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int claimInt = Int.Parse(claim);
```

...

Comment: no it mustn't - I'm telling him to convert his claim to an integer variable first and then use that in his query. Perhaps I could have been clearer...

Comment: ah sorry, but it must be where(x.intClaimID == claimInt)

Answer (score -1):

You don't need that brackets use

```
from x in dbContext.view_ImageVerification_Shortened      
where  x.intClaimID.ToString() == claim
select new { .. }
```

Also `==` is used for comparison `=` is used for assignments.

If you want to compare two incompatible types you need to convert one of them.In this case either use `ToString` on integer (intClaimID), or parse `claim` to integer.

Comment: As in the assignment he get `Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'` you must explicitly cast it.

Comment: -1 Do a string conversion for every item in the collection instead of a when a single string to int conversion? That's hideously inefficient, I wouldn't solve it this way in a million years. Consider what will happen if this is a sql query with LinqToSql or similar?

Comment: yes, that is a big issue.it probably takes millions of years.

Comment: A million years is probably an exaggeration unless you're a truely dreadful developer. Yes, I'm glad you acknowledged your failing, and how slow code would be. Isn't personal growth a wonderful thing? No, don't thank me. Please don't, knowing you're more enlightened is enough!